# Postgresql binding a variable of variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

From reading other posts here I understand what the error is I just don't know how I can fix it in my use case.  I am using a for loop to build a query which will insert multiple lines into my database.

```
  const id = req.body.user_id;
  const data = req.body.data;
  let queryString = '';
  let venue_ids = ``;
  for (let i = 2; i < data.length + 2; i++) {
    if (i === data.length + 1) {
      queryString += `($1, $${i})`;
      venue_ids += `${data[i - 2].id}`;
    } else {
      queryString += `($1, $${i}), `;
      venue_ids += `${data[i - 2].id}, `;
    }
  }
```

I can log my to strings and I get `queryString= ($1, $2), ($1, $3), ($1, $4), ($1, $5), ($1, $6), ($1, $7), ($1, $8), ($1, $9), ($1, $10), ($1, $11)` and `venue_ids = 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2`.

Next I try to make the query:

```
  let sqlText = `INSERT INTO user_matches (user_id, venue_id) VALUES ${queryString}`;
  pool
    .query(sqlText, [id, venue_ids])
    .then((response) => {
      res.send(response.rows);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error saving venue matches', err);
    });
```

The error I get is `bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 11`.
So I see what is happening my `venue_ids` is being interpreted as one variable when I want it to be a variable of variable if that makes sense.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem by using a variable `binded_ids` for the entire binded array.

```
  let binded_ids = [id];
  for (let i = 2; i < data.length + 2; i++) {
    if (i === data.length + 1) {
      queryString += `($1, $${i})`;
      binded_ids.push(data[i - 2].id);
    } else {
      queryString += `($1, $${i}), `;
      binded_ids.push(data[i - 2].id);
    }
  }
```

and then my query:

```
  let sqlText = `INSERT INTO user_matches (user_id, venue_id) VALUES ${queryString}`;
  pool
    .query(sqlText, binded_ids)
    .then((response) => {
      res.send(response.rows);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error saving venue matches', err);
    });
```